# Writing a simple sniffer in web

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web

We have a simple Client-Server sniffer (Wireshark like UI). Server is listening to messages, parsing them and send a parsed messages to the client. We want to move it to Web platform (Web UI instead client)
What is a proper way to do this?

I thought about sending ajax requests to server every x seconds, and update the html, with a new packets. But I don't know if this is a good idea, when we have a big amount of messages. And how many time will packet filtering take, implemented in jQuery (scanning the whole html and hide a not relevant rows)

I see many problems with such solution. Maybe there is a better way to implement this? Maybe there is a way to get asynchronous messages?

Comment: One thought: You could use websockets to get full-duplex messaging.

Comment: I can't use websockets, because there is no support for windows 7 and older IIS, but I've found a SignalR. Thanks